# How to make a add a custom method on the fly in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following class:

```
class Sample 
{
    static function Get()
    {
        echo "Get";
    }
}
```

But I want to enable myself to call:

```
Sample::Put()
```

And then in PHP on the fly add function `Put() {}` to the `Sample` class.

How this is possible?

Comment: Why in the world would you need to do this?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why you want to do so. So that we could provide a way or a solution to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Ok I need to do this....

Comment: It sounds like you _may_ want something like the [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) magic method.

Comment: Patrick Q beat me to it. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: You can do that, but your method will do zero to none of your work. Why do you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [magic function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) `__callStatic` and add all the logic inside that function.

```
class Sample {
  public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
      echo "method called:" . $method;
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a static call as well

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did not remembered this one!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your new method to actually leverage the $this variable, build a closure and set its scope to the target object rather the one in which its born, using http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php.  Something like this (untested):

```
class MyTargetClass {
    protected $customMethods = [];

    protected $something = 'testing';

    public function addCustomMethod($name, Callable $closure)
    {
        $this->customMethods[name] = $closure->bindTo($this);
    }

    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($method, $this->customMethods)) {
            $this->customMethods[$method](...$arguments);
        }
        throw new BadMethodCallException();
    }
}

class MyWorkingClass {
    public function someMethod()
    {
        $method = function($field) {return $this->$field};
        $instance = new MyTargetClass();
        $instance->addCustomMethod('get', $method);
        return $instance->get('something');  //should return "testing"
    }
}
```

Fun fact: This is essentially how Laravel's `Macroable` trait works.